# Estimated localization trajectory of the robot as a list of TF messages using SLAM Toolbox

Tags: slam, navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I obtain the **estimated localization trajectory of the robot as a list of TF messages**? Ideally, at the same frequency as the laser measurements. Background: I want to use that trajectory as the localization of my robot in TF for lookups.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392089/estimated-localization-trajectory-of-the-robot-as-a-list-of-tf-messages-using-slam-toolbox/) by [JehanJay](https://answers.ros.org/users/78556/jehanjay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you create a simple node (or add to your existing autonomy node) a TF subscriber, you can simply obtain the robot pose by obtaining the `map` to `base_link` transformation at your desired capture rate and store that in a list or whatever other format you find useful.

If you use a TF transformation filter on this node with your laser scanner as the subscriber, you can then easily have these things synchronized.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1